# dbcontext.SaveChanges() memory exception in large records EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am facing out of memory exception while executing decontext.savechanges() method.

Actually i need to insert/update 10000+ record into some tables.

ie

```
//insert table 1 // 10000 record <br>
//insert or update record to table 2 //25000 record<br>
//table 3 1000 record<br>

....
.....
.....

db.context.savechanges(); //Exception happening in this line.
```

I got "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" error.

I tried AutoDetectChangesEnabled but its did not help

```
mydbcontext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
mydbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: may be the attribute vale range exed .please show attribute values

Comment: Why not try using Bulk Insert? I believe it is better in performance too

Comment: @Bosco Bulk upload is not practical in my case. I need this way to solve my issue.

Comment: @LDS the insertion of my table depending on some conditions .

Comment: the column value datatype range may out of  range

Comment: where use the savechanges ,whether inside the loop or after add the entity outside the loop

Comment: @LDS i have called save changes after adding all entity outside

Comment: call it inside the loop means after each row insert call savechanges

Comment: @LDS  I need a method something like context.BatchSaveChanges();

Comment: @Bosco any sample method simile to context.BatchSaveChanges();

Answer (score 2):

"Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" - This normally happens to me when I don't dispose my database. The issue probably isn't the amount of records you are trying to update, its probably because those records are kept in the System Memory.

**Solution 1(Recommended)**
Wrap your database functions in 'using' statements which will auto dispose your database context and free up memory

```
public void CreateRange(List<MyModel> modelList){
    using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
    {
       db.MyTable.AddRange(modelList); 
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**
Call 'db.Dispose();' before the end of each method

```
public void CreateRange(List<MyModel> modelList){
    db.MyTable.AddRange(modelList); 
    db.SaveChanges();
    db.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the similar issue, when migrate data, I update many time with SaveChanges() call, however, I didn't Dispose() after the saving, at the beginning, it seems OK, fast, after for a while, it becomes slow, then I got OutOfMemory exception, my total memory cost at 97%.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.BulkInsert(entitiesList);
```

For BulkInsert follow the link
https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Another is sqlBulkCopy
[Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)

If you want to use the Savechanges outsude the loop, so look the below code

```
try
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
 
    foreach (var book in bookList)
    {
        context.Books.Add(book);
    }
    
    context.SaveChanges();
}
finally 
{
    context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
}
```